# How to execute forever command remotely without using full path?

Tags: node.js, powershell, forever

I am trying to execute “forever” command remotely using powershell but I am getting error

> 'forever' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Here is what I am doing. I have the node js script "MyNodeScript.js" which executes the forever command. The script is on the WebServer **"MyWebServer1"**.
Node.Js and Forever is installed on MyWebServer1 globally.

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var winston = require('winston');
    var async = require('async');

    var mycommand = 'forever -p ./logs --sourceDir ../wf_manager --workingDir ../wf_manager start -a --uid "ServiceApp" ServiceApp.js'

    function start(callback) {  
        async.waterfall([
            function (cb) {
                executeCommand(mycommand, false, cb);
            }
        ], function done(err) {
            if (err) {
                winston.error('failed to start all instances by forever:' + err);
            } else {
                winston.info('successfully started all instances by forever');
            }
            callback();
        });
    }

    function executeCommand(command, skip, callback) {
        async.waterfall([
            function (cb) {
                exec(command, cb);
            }
        ], function done(err) {
            if (err) {
                if (skip) {
                    // skip the error
                    callback(null);
                } else {
                    callback(err);
                }
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    }

    module.exports = {
        executeCommand: executeCommand,    
        start: start
    }

    start(function(){});
```

On the same **MyWebServer1** under same folder i have a powershell script "MyPowerShellScript.ps1" which call this node script. The powershell script has only one line

```
node D:\myfolder\maintenance\MyNodeScript.js
```

I can run this powershell script locally on MyWebServer1 and it works fine. But when i try to execute this powershell script as below **from remote machine**

```
 invoke-command -computername MyWebServer1 -filepath \\MyWebServer1\MyFolder\maintenance\MyPowerShellScript.ps1
```

i am getting error

> error: failed to start all instances by forever:Error: Command failed:
>   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "forever -p ./logs --sourceDir 
>   ../wf_manager --workingDir ../wf_manager start -a --uid "ServiceApp"
>   ServiceApp.js"
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error: failed t...ServiceApp.js":String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>       + PSComputerName        : MyWebServer1
>   'forever' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

**Note that i can execute the script remotely without any error if i update "MyNodeScript.js" and use full physical path for the forever command**

```
 var mycommand = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\forever -p ./logs --sourceDir ../wf_manager --workingDir ../wf_manager start -a --uid "ServiceApp" ServiceApp.js'
```

However i would like to use just forever command. The path is already added as Environment variable on MyWebServer1

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the ps1-file like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {powershell.exe -command {d:\blah\MyPowershellscript.ps1 } }
```

Via -filepath your specify a local scriptfile that should be executed remotely. As your script is present on the target system, you can omit that.

Comment: i get error "powershell.exe : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." here is the command i tried "Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {powershell.exe -command {\MyWebServer1\MyFolder\maintenance\MyPowerShellScript.ps1 } }"

Comment: Note MyPowerShellScript.ps1 is on the remote machine ( ie. MyWebServer1 ) and \\MyWebServer1\MyFolder\ i shared folder so other machine can access all files

Comment: in your suggestion above how does it know which remote machine MyPowershellscript.ps1 exists? dont we have to add -ComputerName switch

Comment: When you use `invoke-Command` with `-scriptblock {CODE}` you are executing the CODE as you would, if your were locally connected on the remote machine.
Of course you still need the `-computername` parameter to specify the machine to run your code on, sry for not metioning that in the previous post.

The problem that I see now with your `node is not recognized` error is, that the call via that string does not work. I dont know anything about node, but ist there an executable, that you could call to execute mynodescript.js?

like \programfiles\node\node.exe -script MyNodeScript.js?